# How understand the granularity and block in ClickHouse?

Tags: clickhouse

I am not clear about these two words. 
Whether does one block have a fixed number of rows?
Whether is one block the minimum unit to read from disk?
Whether are different blocks stored in different files?
Whether is the range of one block bigger than granule? That means, one block can have several granules skip indices.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

https://clickhouse.tech/docs/en/operations/table_engines/mergetree/#primary-keys-and-indexes-in-queries

Primary key is sparsed. By default it contains 1 value of each 8192 rows (= 1 granule).

Let's disable adaptive granularity (for the test) -- index_granularity_bytes=0

```
create table X (A Int64) 
Engine=MergeTree order by A 
settings index_granularity=16,index_granularity_bytes=0;

insert into X select * from numbers(32);
```

index_granularity=16 -- 32 rows = 2 granule , primary index have 2 values 0 and 16

```
select marks, primary_key_bytes_in_memory from system.parts where table = 'X';
┌─marks─┬─primary_key_bytes_in_memory─┐
│     2 │                          16 │
└───────┴─────────────────────────────┘
```

16 bytes === 2 values of INT64.

Adaptive index granularity means that granules size various. Because wide rows (many bytes) needs (for performance) fewer (<8192) rows in granule.

index_granularity_bytes = 10MB ~ 1k row * 8129. So each granule have 10MB. If rows size 100k (long Strings), granule will have 100 rows (not 8192).

---

Skip index granules GRANULARITY 3 -- means that an index will store one value for each 3 table granules.

```
create table X (A Int64, B Int64, INDEX IX1 (B) TYPE minmax GRANULARITY 4) 
Engine=MergeTree order by A 
settings index_granularity=16,index_granularity_bytes=0;

insert into X select number, number from numbers(128);
```

128/16 = 8, table have 8 granules, INDEX IX1 stores 2 values of minmax (8/4)

So minmax index stores 2 values -- (0..63) and (64..128)

0..63 -- points to the first 4 table's granules.

64..128 -- points to the second 4 table' granules.

```
set send_logs_level='debug'
select * from X where B=77
[ 84 ] <Debug> dw.X (SelectExecutor): **Index `IX1` has dropped 1 granules**
[ 84 ] <Debug> dw.X (SelectExecutor): Selected 1 parts by date, 1 parts by key, **4 marks** to read from 1 ranges
```

SelectExecutor checked skip index - 4 table granules can be skipped because 77 is not in 0..63 .
And another 4 granules must be read ( **4 marks** ) because 77 in (64..128) -- some of that 4 granules have B=77.

Comment: Thank you so much. Every answer of yours is so substantial.

Comment: I wonder what the mark_bytes mean. The mark_bytes in the first example is 32, 16 bytes greater than primary_key_bytes_in_memory. Is the additional 16 bytes the offset in the column file?

Comment: @gogo One column A. Primary index points marks files. Marks contain 2 pointers to row position the first is an offset in compressed .bin file and the second is an offset in decompressed.

Comment: Get it. And does one read from disk mean reading a compressed block from disk or a granule from disk?

Comment: If the read operation read a granule from disk every time, In your last example, I think it will read skip index of column B at first, and then read the last 4 granules of B.bin to find the row num of 77. At this time, we already get the row num(which is 77) and granule num(which is 4) of 77. Finally, it will use the granule num to read the whole data of granule 4 from A.bin and take the data of num 77 from the granule. Am I right?

Comment: And if so, another question is the amount of rows in granule is different if index_granularity_bytes is not set to 0, So how can I locate the data of row number 77? Is the account of rows of every granule saved in any file?

Answer (score 2):

https://clickhouse.tech/docs/en/development/architecture/#block

Block can contain any number of rows.
For example 1 row blocks:

```
set max_block_size=1;
SELECT * FROM numbers_mt(1000000000) LIMIT 3;

┌─number─┐
│      0 │
└────────┘
┌─number─┐
│      2 │
└────────┘
┌─number─┐
│      3 │
└────────┘

set max_block_size=100000000000;

create table X (A Int64) Engine=Memory;
insert into X values(1);
insert into X values(2);
insert into X values(3);
SELECT * FROM X;

┌─A─┐
│ 1 │
└───┘
┌─A─┐
│ 3 │
└───┘
┌─A─┐
│ 2 │
└───┘
```

3 rows in block

```
drop table X;
create table X (A Int64) Engine=Memory;
insert into X values(1)(2)(3);
select * from X
┌─A─┐
│ 1 │
│ 2 │
│ 3 │
└───┘
```